# Removing Date/Time/Author Name in WordPress Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently developing a WordPress site and would like to know what to change in the template-tags.php file to remove the date, time and author name.

Here is the code which I believe I need to change although each time I do I am greeted with the dreaded screen of death.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'makewp005_posted_on' ) ) :
/**
 * Prints HTML with meta information for the current post-date/time and author.
 */
function makewp005_posted_on() {
    $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
    if ( get_the_time( 'U' ) !== get_the_modified_time( 'U' ) )
        $time_string .= '<time class="updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time>';

    $time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
        esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_date() ),
        esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_modified_date() )
    );

    printf( __( '<span class="posted-on">%1$s</span> <span class="byline"> %2$s</span>', 'makewp005' ),
        sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" rel="bookmark">%2$s</a>',
            esc_url( get_permalink() ),
            $time_string
        ),
        sprintf( '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s">%2$s</a></span>',
            esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
            esc_html( get_the_author() )
        )
    );
}
endif;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the CMS / API to remove them?

I believe this is the option to remove post info;

[image: http://puu.sh/8rzux.png]

> Larger: http://puu.sh/8rzux.png

Comment: I have those options disabled, alas it still appears.

Comment: Well that's just unfortunate! What theme are you using?

Comment: @Tainted this only removes those options from your own administration options. You'll have to remove the entire `print_f` and `sprintf` lines from your template.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want remove everything this function does.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'makewp005_posted_on' ) ) :
/**
 * Prints HTML with meta information for the current post-date/time and author.
 */
function makewp005_posted_on() {}
endif;
```

Comment: I originally did this, and it ended up entirely breaking my site so I had to access the files via FTP and modify them.

Comment: @user3300168 It doesn't make sense. what's the error message